# A wordpress page that has 6 images that link to other parts of the site

Tags: css, wordpress, image

I am making a website for my buddy's small company.

After the index, it has 3 more pages, and one of those pages (family) has 6 child pages (each the name of an artist).

The global width of the theme is 800 px, and I would like each image to be 380 x 380 pixels, laid out in a 2 x 3 grid. When you click on of those images it links to the page that the image corresponds with.

Using the media uploader to organise the sizes and layouts isn't really working, I need padding and such.

I'm totally confused on what I need to do next, should I create a template, so even if I use the media uploader, the template with take over and organise the layout? How can I get any images added to automatically resize to fit? Do I need to do something in the style.css about link style of something, for the padding?

I'm starting to understand a bit about Wordpress development, but I'm so confused about what I am actually trying to do, and finding it hard to articulate.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to create parent div and then set your image size like below code.

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Happy_smiley_face.png" />
</div>

<div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/9500000/happy-face-random-9576699-414-414.jpg" />
</div>

.img-wrap {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

.img-wrap img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mayby it would help you:

```
<div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="..." alt="..." />
</div>
<div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="..." alt="..." />
</div>

.img-wrap {
   width: 380px;
   padding: 0 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
}
.img-wrap:nth-child(2n+1) {
   clear: left;
}
.img-wrap img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```